# How to create line plot on top of horizontal bar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to plot horizontal barplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

x = [dt.date(2021, 12, 12), dt.date(2022, 12, 12), dt.date(2023, 12, 12)]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Date"] = x
df["V1"] = [0, 0.2, 0.8]
df["V2"] = [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]
df.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked = True)
```

Now, I want to add the line plot to this one where y axis will be the same (dates) and x axis will be on the top of the plot. I did the following:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4], x + [dt.date(2024, 12, 12)])
```

But no new content appears and the `y` axis has been destroyed:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: It's not the effect I want to arhcieve